# Using Promise.resolve().then() correctly Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

I have this code:

```js
export class Page {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

  private async openModal(value) {    
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AnotherPage,
      componentProps: {
        "paramID": 123,
        "paramTitle": "Test Title",
        "takenPhoto": "null"
      }
    });

    return await modal.present();
  }

  public async takePicture() {
    this.openModel(null); // here's OK
    Promise.resolve(this.someMethod()).then(this.openModal); // ERROR!!
  }

}
```

On the method `takePicture` I wanna open a modal after of execution of the `Promise.resolve`. On the first execution everything is OK, but on the second one I have an error.

ERROR:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalController' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalController' of undefined
    at tab2.page.ts:25
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at tslib.es6.js:73
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:876)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:69)
    at openModal (tab2.page.ts:22)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Comment: Since the takePicture method is async, couldn’t you just await this.someMethod and then proceed with this.openModal?

Comment: @tlm I don't so, because this.someMethod() returns me a Promise<Object>, so I have to use Promise.resolve(...).then(resolveFunction(value)) to get the Object `value`. But I have to say... I recently started to use typescript, maybe there is another way

Comment: Provide the way you create a `Page` instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
export class Page {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

  private async openModal(value) {    
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AnotherPage,
      componentProps: {
        "paramID": 123,
        "paramTitle": "Test Title",
        "takenPhoto": "null"
      }
    });

    return modal.present();
  }

  public async takePicture() {
    await this.openModel(null); // Need to await a promise
    const data = await this.someMethod()
    await this.openModal(data);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why the error is happening?**
It's because if you want call 'this' inside an implicit function call, you **must** bind to this call the 'this' state. Check it out:

**Before:**

```
  public async takePicture() {
    this.openModel(null); // here's OK
    Promise.resolve(this.someMethod()).then(this.openModal); // ERROR!!
  }
```

**After:**

```
  public async takePicture() {
    this.openModel(null); // here's OK
    Promise.resolve(this.someMethod()).then(this.openModal.bind(this)); // JUST FINE :)
  }
```

**Now** the implicit call will receive the this state to use correctly here:

```
await this.modalController.create({...
```

Se precisar de ajuda em pt-BR pode mandar msg :)

Answer (score 0):

Acording what @VLAZ says (I suggest the reading of the link he provides), you are assumming that `this`, in the context of the openModal() function, is referencing to the context of the class. Since the value of `this` depends only on "how" the function is called, that occurrence of `this` on `this.modalController` is not bound to a context yet, so `this` turns to be undefined, and that is the reason you are getting the error.

You could set `this` to the context of the class before the function is called. Here are some ways:

**1 - Bind `this` in the constructor**

```
constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
}
```

**2 - Use an arrow function which automatically bind `this` to the context of the class (the parent context).**

```
openModal = async (value) => {    
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
       component: AnotherPage,
       componentProps: {
           "paramID": 123,
           "paramTitle": "Test Title",
           "takenPhoto": "null"
       }
     });

     return modal.present();
}
```

I think there are other ways to do it, but those are widely accepted.
Hope it helps!